# How can I make this php cURL execute better?

Tags: php, curl

The following relates to a development site I am working on.  It runs on a cloud server at Ionos (1and1) that runs on CentOS Linux 7.6.1810 (Core) and PHP 7.2.18.

I have a php cronjob that is a parent process.  This script checks a database for records that need to be processed, and for each record that needs to be processed, the parent spawns a child process that is called via php cURL.  I am using the multi_curl feature.

I am currently testing it with 25 dummy records, and will need to be able to process up to 5000 records when I go to production.  Currently, the child processes simply write the result to a log file.

All 25 of the child processes need to start nearly simultaneously; however, fewer than 10 (often 5 or less) start simultaneously and then the remainder start as previous requests finish.  This is not acceptable, and I need to know what to change in my setup (php/mysql/etc) to resolve this and start all child processes as close to simultaneously as possible.

The parent process selects the records to be processed from the database and then spawns child processes via:

```
    $ch = array();
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    $URLs = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_list)) { // process each reservation
    extract($row);

        $url = '/cronjobs/reservation.child.php?jid=' . $j_id;
        array_push($URLs, $url);
}

   foreach ($URLs as $url) {
    $ch[$i] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
    $i++;
}

$active = null;
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($active);


$i = 0;
foreach ($ch AS $i => $c) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
}

curl_multi_close($mh);
```

and the spawned child process currently writes to a log file.  That's it.

Below is a recent log entry:

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Started processing request(s)

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 1: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 2: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 3: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 4: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 5: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 6: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 7: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 8: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 9: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 10: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 11: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 12: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 13: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 14: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 15: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 16: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 17: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 18: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 19: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 20: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 21: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 22: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 23: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 24: Entered processing queue and status updated to "Processing"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 25: Entered processing queue and status updated to “Processing"

So far, the parent php script has spawned 25 children via php cURL… so far so good.  However, all 25 should start at almost the same time, but this is the result:

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 7: Submitted at 13:32:01.97731400 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:01: Request ID 4: Submitted at 13:32:01.98214300 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:02: Request ID 3: Submitted at 13:32:02.99112000 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:02: Request ID 11: Submitted at 13:32:02.99643700 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:02: Request ID 1: Submitted at 13:32:02.99687200 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:02: Request ID 13: Submitted at 13:32:02.99788200 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:03: Request ID 5: Submitted at 13:32:03.00521700 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:03: Request ID 10: Submitted at 13:32:03.00567200 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:33: Request ID 14: Submitted at 13:32:33.97885900 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:34: Request ID 25: Submitted at 13:32:34.98112300 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:38: Request ID 12: Submitted at 13:32:38.98721700 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:38: Request ID 6: Submitted at 13:32:38.98854100 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:43: Request ID 21: Submitted at 13:32:43.00379900 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:45: Request ID 2: Submitted at 13:32:45.00574600 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:53: Request ID 15: Submitted at 13:32:53.05596300 and status updated to "Processed"

2019-05-07 13:32:53: Request ID 20: Submitted at 13:32:53.05604100 and status updated to “Processed"

Of the 25 children that were spawned, only 15 actually processed, and, rather than all starting about 13:32:01, they took nearly a minute to spawn.

I monitored top during processing and the cpu usage never went above 2.x percent.

In the plesk logs for the site, some of the children had the following error:

504 GET /cronjobs/reservation.child.php?jid=8&jeid=027093&starttime=1557250321.6883&timeToStartProcess=1557250380&timeToSleep=58307153 HTTP/1.0

as well as

mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds

and

End of script output before headers: jumpseat.reservation.child.php

and

*152510 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream

I am running php 7.2.18 has have tried FastCGI and both flavors of FPM.  I also tried various combinations of PHP-FPM settings.

What do I need to do/change/configure to be able to start up to several thousand processed nearly simultaneously.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't do this! Invoke the CLI php directly, you are going to completely tie up your HTTP server.

Comment: Okay... can you point me to a url that describes how to implement this?

Comment: Questions... can a cli php script be called via crontab? ... and can a cli php script cURL out to other cli scripts?  Thanks

Comment: No URL is required, simply run your PHP script via the PHP CLI application, for example: `php myFile.php`. And yes, this can be executed from a crontab, and yes, a cli script can perform a HTTP request via cURL. As far as your code is concerned, the only difference between a CGI script and a CLI script is the output, for CLI you obviously want to echo text and not HTML.

Comment: FYI: Even if you use the CLI method, if you try to `start up to several thousand processed nearly simultaneously`, you will completely saturate the server's CPU and RAM resources (you will DoS yourself), and very likely hit hard limits imposed to prevent DoS attacks on the remote end of the link. If you need to perform so many requests simultaneously you need to re-think your design, it's simply infeasible without investing in an incredible amount of hardware. Rule of thumb, plan for at most 2 processes per CPU core, no more.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just hitting the URLs have a look at this alternate implementation:

https://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/

You can set `$rolling_window` (number of parallel threads) to your liking, in terms of server resources.

Comment: Thanks... will look at it.

Comment: @David note that he is trying to (ab)use the HTTP server to spawn local async workers (note the lack of a fqdn in the url) from a master process. What he is asking for amounts to essentially a DoS attack due to the requirement to "start up to several thousand processed nearly simultaneously" performing HTTP requests.

Comment: @Geoffrey Well yes, potentially. I can't think of a good reason myself for a script like this, and architecturally it would likely need large fundamental changes. There are better, less intensive methods for DoS anyway. Other readers may find the above implementation useful.

Comment: Relax guys... it is not a DOS attack.  I prepend $securebaseurl to create a fdqn, and $securebaseurl is retrieved from a configuration file and changes based on whether it is my development or production site.  The requests above are made to a third party provider that I pay to send dtmf tones to my employers reservation line for my clients at a specific time, and all requests need to have an equal shot at being first, hence the need to send all requests nearly simultaneously.  I am looking for any more elegant solutions.

Comment: @alanpollenz No, I am not stating it's an actual attempt to perform a DoS attack, but the effect will be the same. If you''re attempting to ensure it's a fair chance for any to be first, then the proper solution would be to select a random client from your data set and try that one single client, if it fails then move onto the next random client.